# find repeating patterns of same number in a list of numbers

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find the repeating pattern of same number in a list numbers.
eg.

```
flag_list = [6, 4, 4, 20, 4, 4, 4, 4, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16]
```

Desired output: it will be a list of lists of all repeating numbers.
eg.

```
repeating_list = [[4, 4],
                  [4, 4, 4, 4],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0],
                  [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                  ]
```

I tried in these lines:

```
main_list = []
temp = []
for i in range(0,len(flag_list)):
   
    if flag_list[i-1]==flag_list[i]:
        if flag_list[i-1] not in temp:
            temp.append(flag_list[i-1])
        temp.append(flag_list[i])
 
    main_list.append(temp)
    temp.clear()
```

Please share any resource regarding this that'll be a big help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
flag_list = [6, 4, 4, 20, 4, 4, 4, 4, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0,
             16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,
             16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16]

from itertools import groupby

[G for _,g in groupby(flag_list) if len(G:=list(g))>1]
```

*NB. this code uses an [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) and requires python ≥ 3.8*

or using [extended iterable unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/) as suggested by @wjandrea, compatible with python ≥ 3.0:

```
[g for _k, (*g,) in groupby(flag_list) if len(g) > 1]
```

output:

```
[[4, 4],
 [4, 4, 4, 4],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0],
 [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

###### variant format

you can easily "compress" the output if the form `(value, number_repeats)` using:

```
[(n, len(G)) for n,g in groupby(flag_list) if len(G:=list(g))>1]
```

output:

```
[(4, 2), (4, 4), (0, 6), (0, 2), (16, 19), (0, 46)]
```